# Powershell: Folder Browser/File Browser path

Tags: powershell, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

I am kind of new to Powershell and just want to check if something is possible.

I understand there is a way to allow me to get the path of an individual file and even multiple files with the OpenFile dialog.   I also understand there is a way for the user to select a folder with the folderbrowser dialog.

What I am looking for is a way for the user to select a path, whether that be a folder or a file(with multiselect).

I currently have a script which allows the user the select a folder path which is then used in my script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderBrowser.SelectedPath -Recurse -File |
ForEach-Object{
$_.creationtime=$($_.CreationTime.AddDays($daysTextBox.Text)) }
```

I want to update the existing script to allow for files or folders to be selected rather than duplicating the script.

I've searched extensively online but so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: I dont think there is a windows form allowing to pick folder or file with multi-select function. IMH, I would create a message box to let the user select: "Pick a folder", "Pick a file", "Cancel/Done" - the user selects either multiple folder and/or multiple files - the result is your data to process further.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I’ve decided to create a tabbed form and have one tab for folders and one tab for individual items.

Comment: Mind to share your result with us?